# ForeignKey lookups in Django including non-existent ones

Tags: django

Given the following models:-

```
class Player(models.Model):
    pass

class Game(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField(unique=True)
    player_chosen = models.ManyToManyField(
        Player,
        through='GamePlayerMembership'
    )

class GamePlayerMembership(models.Model):
    game = models.ForeignKey(Game)
    player = models.ForeignKey(Player)
    injured = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

What is the most efficient way to get a player's memberships from the last 10 games in which the player wasn't injured.

For some games, there may not even exist a GamePlayerMembership for that player and that game but if there was a game then I need that item in the list of 10 to be None.

I was thinking that if I could get hold of the games for which there is not a membership for that player, combine them with the games for which there was, and they weren't injured, then take the last 10, then that would do but I don't really know how to go about the first bit.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Game.objects.filter(gameplayermembership__player=player, gameplayermembership__injured=False)
```

or:

```
Game.objects.exclude(gameplayermembership__player=player)
```

Comment: The exclude clause does help - but what I really need is the player's memberships from those games (or None if there was no membership).

That code gives me the games and I can't see how to get the list of memberships without thousands of db lookups.

Comment: Why do you want the membership, and not the game ?
Maybe something like  `GamePlayerMembership.objects.filter(player=player, injured=False)` gives you what you need ?